# React Native: error: constructor MapsPackage in class MapsPackage cannot be applied to given types

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I tried the both solution `new MapsPackage(this)` and `new MapsPackage()` .But nothing works for me.

And I see the MapsPackage class, The constructor are given as below

They handling the both compatibility. with argument and without argument.

```
  public MapsPackage(Activity activity) {
  } // backwards compatibility

  public MapsPackage() {
  }
```

Comment: Hi do you found any solutions for this issue

Answer (score 0):

your information doesn't sufficient.

you can see this error when adding new module in

```
    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      packages.add(new LocationPackage());
      return packages;
    }
```

you should care about the point you import new module. This error occurs when you want to add package but import module. for example when you want to write `new LocationPackage()`, you write `new LocationModule()`.